# Getting value with array

Tags: php, json

I am struggling to get the value of an element in a particular array. I would like to get the value of the "logo" in this case to return "Logo Google 2013 Official.svg" from the code below. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<html>

<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="google" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q'];


$url_2 = 
"http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?   
action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=$search&rvsection=0&continue=";
$res_2 = file_get_contents($url_2);
$data_2 = json_decode($res_2);


?>

<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $search; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data_2->query->pages as $r): 

?>

<li>

<?php foreach($r->revisions[0] as $a); 
echo $a; ?>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The resulting `$url_2` is http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=google&rvsection=0&continue=

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the whole code? I can't see any logo or other element holding that filename anywhere in this code.

Comment: @tkounenis Hi I'm positive - just press search and there in the resulting text array is "logo = Logo Google 2013 Official.svg". Technically I suppose it is in the Infobox element. Please let me know if you still can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression to capture what you want:

```
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data_2->query->pages as $r): ?>
    <?php foreach($r->revisions[0] as $a): ?>
    <li>
        <?php
            preg_match_all('/ logo += +([^|]+)/', $a, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
            echo trim($result[0][0]); // prints 'Logo Google 2013 Official.svg'
        ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: excellent thanks very much! Sorry to be a pain I was wondering whether this can be generalised to return the logo value from the Infobox for any company on Wikipedia?

Comment: In practice, it will return everything it finds after the first occurance of " logo = " up until the first pipeline ('**|**') character. After a brief research, there is not always a "logo = " string in the output of your link, so it is not guaranteed that you will get a logo back.

Comment: Thank again in your research could you see a way of getting logo = string using a different link?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a consistent way to get this 100% automatically. I would try Google's [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) and get the first image probably.

Comment: sorry to keep pestering but I've just tried the same script with "Yahoo!" which does have logo = string and the preg_match_all gives me 0 results. Any ideas?